# How can I add some line spacing here, I want there to be a bit of a gap between the lines

Tags: equations

```
\begin{align*}
\textrm{PED}&= \frac{\textrm{\% change in quantity demanded}}{\textrm{\% change in price}} \\ 
&= \frac{(103-150)/150}{(868-434)/434}\\
&= \frac{-0.31}{1} = -0.31
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\begin{align*}
\textrm{PED}&= \frac{\textrm{\% change in quantity demanded}}{\textrm{\% 
change in price}} \\[1cm] 
&= \frac{(103-150)/150}{(868-434)/434}\\[1cm] 
&= \frac{-0.31}{1} = -0.31
\end{align*}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `spreadlines` environment from `mathtools` (which loads `amsmath`). This environment takes an argument, which sets the value of `\jot` (spacing added between lines of multiline environments).

Demo:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{spreadlines}{1.5ex}
\begin{align*}
\textrm{PED}&= \frac{\textrm{\% change in quantity demanded}}{\textrm{\% change in price}} \\
&= \frac{(103-150)/150}{(868-434)/434}\\
&= \frac{-0.31}{1} = -0.31
\end{align*}
\end{spreadlines}

\begin{align*}
\textrm{PED}&= \frac{\textrm{\% change in quantity demanded}}{\textrm{\% change in price}} \\
&= \frac{(103-150)/150}{(868-434)/434}\\
&= \frac{-0.31}{1} = -0.31
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using the `\setlength{\jot}{<size>pt}` command as suggest from the very nice user @Bernard you can use also the `split` enviroment like this MWE.
I have increase very much the spacing between the equations (**20pt**).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\setlength{\jot}{20pt} 
\begin{split}
\text{PED} &= \frac{\text{\% change in quantity demanded}}{\text{\% change in price}} \\
&= \frac{(103-150)/150}{(868-434)/434}\\
&= \frac{-0.31}{1} = -0.31
\end{split}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]